# PDF generation from html pages

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

To generate pdf file from html page I have used libraries like MPDF , FPDF, DOMPDF etc.

In each pdf library I found following issues.

- mpdf causes unnecessary page breaks
- FPDF needs more writting. etc

When I used DOMPDF it worked fine but large table didn't expanded to next page and pdf broke without generating next pages.

Then I searched for another pdf library and I came to know about **TCPDF**.

SO I want to know what are the disadvantages of "TCPDF"?

Answer (score 2):

A great alternative for PDF generation is **wkhtmltopdf**. It has a smooth integration and the result is awesome. You will have to install the binary into your server, though. If you're on a VPS or dedicated, this will not be a problem.

There's a PHP lib for using it, you can find it here: https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy

Also, there's a nice solution for the large table problem you have. Maybe it can help you with another lib too, take a look here: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=566