# how to create html table in fpdf

Tags: html, oracle, fpdf

I am newbie.
I have a problem how to convert html table with fpdf.
This is my html code

```
<html>
<body>

<table border=1 align=center>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>PO1</td>
<td>PO2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LO1</td>
<td> "THIS WILL TAKE THE VALUE FROM DATABASE "  </td>
<td> "THIS WILL TAKE THE VALUE FROM DATABASE "  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LO2</td>
<td> "THIS WILL TAKE THE VALUE FROM DATABASE "  </td>
<td> "THIS WILL TAKE THE VALUE FROM DATABASE "  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF generation from html pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128812/pdf-generation-from-html-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please take a look the example at http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php